# Check my UML Class Diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image]

Can someone check my class diagram because I am not too good at drawing this type of uml diagram

1. A User can be a PersonalUser or a BusinessUser
2. An Administrator is a special type of PersonalUser
3. A PersonalUser or BusinessUser can create many Auction
4. But an Auction can be created by only one PersonalUser or only one BusinessUser
5. There an Auction cannot exist without an PersonalUser or a BusinessUser
6. An Auction can contain only one Item
7. An Item can be in only one Auction
8. An Item cannot exist without an Auction
9. An Auction cannot exist without an Item
10. An Item has one Category
11. Category can has many item
12. An Item  cannot exist without a category
13. A Category can has a Parent Category but this is not mandatory
14. A Category can has many Attributes
15. But an Attribute is for only one Category
16. An Attribute cannot exist a Category
17. An Attribute can has many AttributeOption
18. But an AttributeOption is linked to only one Attribute
19. An AttributeOption cannot exist without an Attribute
20. An Auction can has many bids
21. A bid is only for one auction
22. A Bid cannot exist without an Auction and a Personal User or a BusinessUser
23. An Item can has many picture
24. A picture is only for once item and a picture cannot exist without an Item
25. A User can create many ForumTopics but a ForumTopic can be created only by one User
26. A ForumTopics can contain one or more ForumMessage
27. A ForumTopic cannot exist without a User and a ForumMessage cannot exist without a ForumTopic
28. A BusinessUser can has many BusinessContactNumber but a BusinessContactNumber is only for one BusinessUser
29. A BusinessContactNumber cannot exist without a Business

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, you used a lot of aggregations. This is quite uncommon. I have never seen a good example of when an aggregation is justified. It's usually either a plain association (no whole-part relationship) or a composition (the part is deleted when the whole is deleted).

*Cannot exists without* does not imply aggregation. A proper multiplicity is sufficient. *Can create* does not imply aggregation. Creation is usually modeled with an appropriately stereotyped use-relation (i.e. dashed arrow), unless an association between the creator and the creation exists (in which case creation need not be mentioned explicitly).

> 4 But an Auction can be created by only one PersonalUser or only one BusinessUser.

Then the multiplicity of the Auction-PersonalUser association cannot be 1 at the PersonalUser end (because the Auction might have been created by a BusinessUser) and the multiplicity of the Auction-BusinessUser association cannot be 1 at the BusinessUser end (for much the same reason). Use 0..1 as multiplicity, but beware of what I will write about 3.

> 3 A PersonalUser or BusinessUser can create many Auction

This is equivalent to *a User can create many Auction*.

> 6 An Auction can contain only one Item
>
> 7 An Item can be in only one Auction
>
> 8 An Item cannot exist without an Auction
>
> 9 An Auction cannot exist without an Item

Then there is a single association between Item and Auction with multiplicity of 1 at both ends. Don't make aggregations out of it and don't use two associations for it.

> 13 A Category can has a Parent Category but this is not mandatory

That would be made clear if you label the association ends.

> 25 A User can create many ForumTopics but a ForumTopic can be created only by one User

This is only vaguely related to Auctions and might as well exists independent of them. Put the Forum stuff into a separate package. Then maybe the auction stuff and the user stuff also deserve a separate packages.

BTW: You did not mention the Bidding Service. It seems solely to model the concept of *theses objects do not exist in thin air, they are actually used by some software*. In that case, leave it out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed, i gonna make the corrections. The BiddingService is class which implements many method such as for e.g. a user may login and the login check method is handled by the bidding service, bidding service handles overall methods such as deleting forumtopics, creating forumposts, the biddingservice connect to the database through, should i ommit it??

Comment: @Noor Not necessarily. But you should probably cut down on its associations. An association usually translates into an attribute when turned into code. Does the Bidding service have attributes for all the associations you enterd?

Comment: @Osward No Bidding Service don't have any attributes at all, it only implement methods such as checkcredentials and so on.

Comment: @Noor Then you should remove the associations and add *uses*-relations from the BiddingService to the appropriate classes.

Comment: @Oswald: +1 for response.  Fully agree re. proliferation of aggregation, use plain associations instead.

Comment: @Noor: `BiddingService` worries me.  Sounds like it contains - or at least routes - most of the behaviour for the model?  Which has all the hallmarks of the "anemic domain model" anti-pattern...

Answer (score 1):

I largely agree with previous respondent, so I will present only differences and additional opinions.

To be a bit more precise, "Can create..." should be depicted using dependency relationship (not uses).

1. It is not entirely equivalent if some distinction should exist. You might use User class with an enumeration or UserType class if you want to avoid enumerations for some reason.

6.-9. So no Auction or Item object can exist. Either loosen the relationship in one way and use composition or merge those two to one class or create an association class.

1. Maybe one category can contain many subcategories? If true, edit the corresponding multiplicity.
2. Same as 4., view the other answer.

Also rethink the amount of classes in your design. Classes are not just data holders, they should have behaviour. What will be the behaviour of AttributeOption or Attribute or BusinessContact etc? Getters and setters do not count for a behaviour... I guess you planned to have all of this behaviour in BidingService, so I advise you to remove it and split those methods according to what class of objects should be responsible for behaviour achieved through the respective method.